# how to parameterize which namedAccount I connect a contract to inside of a hardhat task?

Tags: solidity, ethers.js, hardhat, hardhat-deploy

I want to be able to switch between which account calls the function by passing the name as the parameter to the task:

`yarn hardhat doSomething --name deployer --network localhost`

```js
task(
    "doSomething",
    "calls doSomething on most recent Foobar contract"
)
    .addParam("name", "your account name from the namedAccount config")
    .setAction(async ( namedAccount) => {
        console.log("grabbing and connecting namedAccount to contract...")
        const foobar = await ethers.getContract(
            "Foobar", namedAccount
        )
        console.log("Success!")
        await tokenWizardAuto.doSomething()
}
```

However this returns: `Error: invalid signer or provider`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could indicate the position of the account to be used as a parameter and store an array of accounts in an env file. Like:

```
task(
    "doSomething",
    "calls doSomething on most recent Foobar contract"
)
    .addParam("index", "your account name from the namedAccount config")
    .setAction(async ( namedAccount) => {
const MNEMONICS: string = process.env.MNEMONICS!;
const accounts: string[] = MNEMONICS.split(",");
const account =hre.ethers.Wallet.fromMnemonic(accounts[taskArgs.index]);
```